# Generics types in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, observablecollection

I have three similar methods like this for types Loan, Client and Book. I´m a programming student  and I would to know if is possible to pass in the parameter, a generic type which match with this 3 classes, I mean pass between brackets a different type like `<T>`, having only one method for the three classes. I tried `<object>` but it doesn´t work.

```
public void LoadStoreLoans(ObservableCollection<Loan> loansCollection)
{
     IList<Loan> loans = db.Query<Loan>(); //db4o 
     loansCollection = loans != null ? new ObservableCollection<Loan>(loans) : new ObservableCollection<Loan>();
}
```

Thnks.

Comment: Does three class implement a common interface or inherit from an abstract base class?

Comment: @Selman22 They have no relation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, and I suggest to make the collection a return value if you always replace it (which isn't the purpose of the observable collection):

```
public ObservableCollection<T> LoadStoreCollection<T>()
{
     IList<T> queried = db.Query<T>();
     return queried != null ? new ObservableCollection<T>(queried) : new ObservableCollection<T>();
}
```

For your first try with object: I have never used db4o but I think it uses the given type parameter (`Load` or `T`) in the `Query` function to infer which table to query. Given `object` yields an error as there is no table for `object`. You need to specify a surrogate type or better - a generic type parameter - which will be bound the the actual type during execution. When called with `T = Loan`, the `db.Query` call can query the `Loan` table as if you would have written `db.Query<Loan>` in the first place.

As the collection was a parameter in the question, one could think you'd call the function multiple times for the same `T`, but:
Always reinitialising the same observable collection variable with `new` disables all benefits a observable collection can give, for example you'll never receive a collection changed event (because you listen on the replaced collection), you can't bind it to a control and if you register some other object to the event, you'll introduce a memory hole :)

Comment: My answer would have been the same, there is no reason to downvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create an empty interface, and implement it for your classes.Just in order to make this constraint possible:

```
public interface ICommon 
{

}

public void LoadStoreLoans<T>(ObservableCollection<T> loansCollection)
     where T : ICommon
{
     IList<T> loans = db.Query<T>(); //db4o 
     loansCollection = loans != null ? new ObservableCollection<T>(loans) : new ObservableCollection<T>();
}
```

Comment: `IList<Loan>` should be `<T>`?

Comment: there are 2 more `<Loan>`.

Comment: I cant see any benefit in defining that marker interface for constraining the method. The whole logic in that method is generic and I cant see any reason why one should add a constraint to that method. The sense of this method is get data from a storage and return that data in an observable collection. No constraint needed.

Comment: @Scordo It's necessary to restrict types that can be passed to the function.OP wants to pass just three classes (or maybe more,but specific classes),if we don't use constraint anything can be passed to the function like int,double or any kind of class.

Comment: Retrictions are ok if there a good reasons for them. In this case there is no common thing for the 3 types, as you can see that there are no members of the 3 types used that are specific to the 3 types. So there is no reason to restrict the method. It only gets more complex. I know the OP asked for it, but I would have asked why the hell he wants it, after looking at the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    public void LoadStoreLoans<T>(ObservableCollection<T> loansCollection)
    {
        IList<T> loans = db.Query<T>(); //db4o 
        loansCollection = loans != null ? new ObservableCollection<T>(loans) : new ObservableCollection<T>();
    }
```

It really depends what type parameter `db.Query<T>()` expects.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for correct?

```
public void Load<T>(ObservableCollection<T> collection)
{
  var items = db.Query<T>(); //db4o 
  collection = items != null ? new ObservableCollection<T>(items) : new ObservableCollection<T>();
}
```

Hope that helps :)